# Close form but keep application running

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form that I can open by pressing a button. All I want is to open this form and start the application and when I press the close button, I want to hide the form, but the application should still be running.

When I press the button again I want it to show that the application is still running, not to start over.
I used `e.Cancel = true;`, but `Cancel` gives me an error like an extension is missing.

How is this caused, and how can I solve this?

Edited:

error: "Error   1   'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Close' and no extension method 'Close' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
"

I used "cancel", and "close" and for both of them is the same error.

```
 e.Cancel = True;
 Hide();
```

This button opens a new form wich calculates me a sum between two hours. I have a timer that counts seconds. When I press again the button after hidding this form, I want to continue the counting, not to start it over.

Comment: The exact error message could be relevant. Please include it in your question.

Comment: does this buttonclick opens another application or just a form in this application ? It is not at all clear to me what you want

Comment: Use [Form.OnFormClosing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event instead, it have the right event arg [FormClosingEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong event, use this instead:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormColosingEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();
}
```

Comment: Do I have to declare something before? It don`t recognize "FormColosingEventArgs", it starts when I run it, but is the same problem, when I want to reopen the form, it starts over.

Comment: @RuslanPopescu how are you reopening the form?

Comment: When I press the button, the form is opening and the calculation begin. I want to close the form by pressing [x] and when I press the same button again, to show up my form that wasn't stop the calculation. The calculation must proceed in background. I want only to hide the form when I press [x], not to stop and close it.